# mysql error SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql

I am relatively new to php and have been following a tutorial for a beginner project. This project includes a database using the DBO object with mysql. I am using MAMP to run php. When I try to run my project it gives me the error in the title. Here is my code for database setup:

```
<?php
  $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=assignment_tracker';
  $username = 'root';

  try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username);
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error = "Database Error: ";
    $error .= $e->getMessage();
    include('view/error.php');
    exit();
  }
```

I am able to enter the phpmyadmin page. Looking at the user table in the mysql database shows this:
[image]

My port in the php.ini file is 8889. (My apache port is 8888 but my mysql is 8889 not sure which one it should be set to.) Looking at other answers on this website have been really confusing for me so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share how you set `8889`. Also you are using the default `root` user with no password? You really should not use the `root` user for any web app. Although, if it were a port error it should timeout, or not connect, not through a denial.

Comment: I edited the php.ini file and changed these lines:
mysqli.default_port = 8889 and
mysqli.default_host = 8889

Comment: You are using PDO not `mysqli`. Try `mysql:host=localhost;port=8889;dbname=assignment_tracker`

Comment: @user3783243 Oh whoops didn't realize it said mysqli, anyway I have ```mysql:host=localhost;port=8889;dbname=assignment_tracker``` as my dsn.

Comment: Same behavior? And there is no password for root user, right?

Comment: Correct, The error is the same and there is no password for root. (in my myphpadmin the password for root is null)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding mysql's port to the `$dns` and add the password (if it's not null) as part of the connection. Try this

```
<?php

$dsn      = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=8889;dbname=assignment_tracker';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

try{
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
}catch (PDOException $e){
    $error = "Database Error: ";
    $error .= $e->getMessage();
    include('view/error.php');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: (The default password for `root` is null... although that user should never be being used for a web app)

Comment: It is empty which `$db = new PDO($dsn, $username);` would map to.

Comment: Ok when I copy paste your code I get the error: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused". When I change the 127.0.0.1 back to localhost the error is the same: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"